# Using Google QUERY to return MAX value AND corresponding values from other columns

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, google-query-language

I have the following dataset (see image): Columns A to E contains WORK SITE inspections records (**SITE ID** (A), **Inspection type** (B), **Site status** (C), **Inspecting Company** (D) and **Date of inspection** (E)).

In the next Sheet (green zone from G to J) I have a sorted list of WORK SITES (Column G) for which I am trying to build a query expression to retrieve the LATEST date of inspection (=MAX value), CORRESPONDING Inspecting Company and CORRESPONDING Site status, WHERE Type of Inspection is = 'ANNUAL' i.e. `B = 'ANNUAL'`.
In the example below, for the WORK_SITE_1 the desired result should be:

```
WORK_SITE_1 - 13/Nov/2019 - COMP_8 - Operational
```

I was hoping to use ARRAYFORMULA to avoid placing formulas into each row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="","",VLOOKUP(G2:G,A2:E,{5,4,3},FALSE)))
```

The above however gets me the first instance of the inspection date only and not the LATEST date.
For the time being, I use the following QUERIES in each row H:

```
=QUERY($A$1:$E$14,"SELECT MAX(E) WHERE A = '"&G2&"' LABEL MAX(E) '' ",0)
```

and in Column I for each row

```
=QUERY($A$2:$E$14,"SELECT D, C WHERE E = date '"&TEXT(H2, "yyyy-mm-dd") &"' AND A = '"&G2&"' ",0)
```

I would appreciate a hint on this.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

without getting too deep into it, i think you can just sort the range of the vlookup by date descending and it'll return the latest one.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="","",VLOOKUP(G2:G,SORT(A2:E,5,FALSE),{5,4,3},FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thank you, @MattKing. Though your solutions works, it does not take into account that "In addition to that, we also need the resultant list by type of inspection, i.e. return only B = 'ANNUAL' which pushes me towards QUERY. "